# Truncating Data in Variables, cant get Full Data

Tags: json, typescript, post, nativescript, angular2-forms

i am new to nativescript angular2 programming. I want to post large json data to a server. but when i create a json format data, data becomes truncated. I think reason is the size of the holding variable.

//my code is:

```
let headers = new Headers({ "Content-Type": "application/json" });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
let body= 
{
  "id": "1002345",
  "weekday": [{
    "item1" :" data1",//string
    "item2":" data2",//string
    "item3":" data3",//string
    "item4":" data4",//string
    "item5":" data5",//string
    "item6":" data6",//base64 string of an image
    "item7":" data7"//base64 string of an image
}]
```

};

when i try to print `body` then data becomes truncated!! 
1. Which variable can hold large data?
2. Any alternate method to post large data?
Please help me out.

//json Format:
`{"id":"1002345","weekday":{"item1":"nil","item2":"nil","item3":"nil","item4":"nil","item5":0,"item6":"nil","item7":"nil"}}`

//actual Json data:

`{"id":"1002345","weekday":{"item1":"nil","item2":"nil","item3":"nil","item4":"nil","item5":0,"item6":"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`

here item6 s some part and item7 is missing!

Comment: It would help if you shared the actual (/mocked, but of the same length) data.

Comment: @pkanev updated !. please take alook !

Comment: @pkanev added actual data.. please help me out

Comment: When you say you print `body` what do you mean? If you mean you used `console.log()` than you are probably just seeing the output truncated. Do you have any reason to believe the variable itself isn't being stored correctly?

Answer (score 1):

If by "when i try to print `body`" you mean you output it with `console.log()` you need to be aware that on most systems (including Chrome, Firefox, IE, even nodejs) the debug output from `console.log()` is truncated to prevent it going over a reasonable length for display.

Unless you have some other reason to believe your variable has truncated, it probably hasn't been.